# Python packages not building properly

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I am trying to create a python package of a directory which looks like this.

[image]

My `setup.py` looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='incr-consumer',
    version='0.0.1',
    description="BBB",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={x: ['*.csv', '*.json', '*.txt', '*.sql', '*.yml', '*.cfg'] for x in find_packages()},
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[line for line in open('requirements.txt')],
    options={"bdist_wheel": {"universal": True}},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'archiver=incr_consumer.src.kkk:main',
            'produce=incr_consumer.util.ppp:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

I have successfully installed the package via `python install -e .`
When I try to see if the package works I don't see the module available to me.

[Note: I have an `__init__.py` within src. Please let me know why is this happening, and what can I do to resolve this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably also need to have an `__init__.py` within `incr_consumer` to mark it as a package.

If you do `print(find_packages())` in your setup script, it's probably not currently enumerating all packages correctly.

Comment: I added the `__init__.py` and still there is no src

Comment: I figured it out imports worked like incr-consumer.src.kkk

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [`package_dir={'incr_consumer': 'src'}`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) (see also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data)) and then specify everything else relative to the `src` directory (including the console scripts).